# Santander Boleto Registrado via XML

Tags: php, web-service, boleto

Estou tentando migrar o sistema para os boletos registrados do Santander. Consegui finalmente hoje que me mandassem o manual de 2017.

1 - Quando tento acessar o link para gerar ticket ele avisa "403 Forbidden"

> https://ymbdlb.santander.com.br/dl-ticket-services/TicketEndpointService

2 - É uma requisição SOAP? No manual sempre falam em 'XML', vi que parece ser uma requisição SOAP, mas onde está o WSDL?

3 - Alguma ideia de como assinar com o tal certificado 'client' num Linux / PHP?

Comment: olá..sobre o certificado, Luis Antonio falou sobre o PersonalSign 2 Pro ...mas por que nao pode escolher o PersonalSign 1 ou PersonalSign 2 sendo eles mais baratos? https://www.globalsign.com/en/personalsign/pricing/ obrigado desde ja

Comment: Aonde você conseguiu o manual do santander?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nauro, o serviço do banco Santander, só aceita soap, não funciona com https request, mesmo usando certificado. Usando Linux, tentei com ruby(savon) e python(zeep), só tive exito com nodejs, consegui que o serviço client autenticasse usando o certificado e passando a senha. Não serve certificado sem um AC, autoridade certificadora. Adquiri o certificado pela GlobalSign, tipo (PersonalSign 2 Pro), https://www.globalsign.com/en/, $89,00. Depois do processo de compra finalizado, você receberá um arquivo pfx, dele você poderá extrair seu certificado e sua chave, anexando-os ao seu serviço.
Quando estiver com o certificado em mãos, você pode acessar   https://ymbdlb.santander.com.br/dl-ticket-services/TicketEndpointService?wsdl e terá o retorno das operações.
A escolha do plano **PersonalSign 2 Pro** é porque ele certifica a existência da organização/empresa, isso foi solicitado pelo Santander.

Comment: @Luiz fiz todo esse procedimento que você fez, estou usando o php para fazer a integração, quando eu faço o request do meu client usando o __getFunctions() ele me retorna esse erro: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from https://ymbdlb.santander.com.br/dl-ticket-services/TicketEndpointService?wsdl : failed to load external entity https://ymbdlb.santander.com.br/dl-ticket-services/TicketEndpointService?wsdl chegou a passar por isso ou sabe como resolver?

Comment: Luiz qual lib voce usou para fazer as chamas SOAP com NodeJS? Estou tentando com a node SOAP mas estou recebendo erro `{ TicketResponse: { message: 'Error: java.lang.NullPointerException', retCode: -1 } }`

Alguma dica?

Comment: Eu usei esse modulo, https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap. Esse erro ocorria quando a estrutura de dados enviada na solicitação não estava de acordo com o que é requisitado pelo serviço Santander.

Comment: Alguem conhece uma solução opensource (de preferencia em php, mas pode ser outra linguagem tb, que rode em linux) pra fazer o registro online do boleto com o Santander?